# how to tell in code if we are running from a testmethod .net test

Tags: c#, .net, testing

Is there a way to know when code is being called from running a test method?

```
bool MyMethod()
{
    if ( /* are we running a test? */ )
    {
        return true; // otherwise this will fail from the automated build script
    }
    else
    {
        // run the proper code
    } 
}
```

and please spare me the "this is a really bad idea" comments :)

Comment: this depends on your testing framework, please elaborate.

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  A really really bad idea.  A stupendously bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You recognize this may be a bad idea, but you may not be aware of the alternatives. **You should look into [mocking frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) - they can provide a way to inject alternative implementations into your code at runtime in your unit tests.** This is an established practice to allow code to behave differently in test and production.

*On to the main question.*

**This depends on the unit test framework you are using.** I'm not aware of a specific feature in NUnit (for example) that reports you are in a test. Other frameworks (like MS Test) may very well provide this. However, it's easy to do yourself.

**If you're binding to source code,** just use a [#define](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fyt3yck0x(VS.71).aspx&ei=PR6eS9yeDIG78gb08-i6Cg&usg=AFQjCNEQtFhxVmRHUexJcgoiHFHH-BzTqQ&sig2=OoQUdPsV1vU2_gysL9_rkA) directive to conditionally define some variable you can branch on.

**If you're binding to a library,** I would recommend creating your own class that you use to track whether you are in a unit test or real code, and set that class up in the [TestFixture setup method](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.2) to indicate you are running a test. You could also use the [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) as a way of avoiding writing a special class.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'll spare you my "this **is** a really bad idea" comment.

You can just give the method a parameter `bool isTestMode`.

Comment: What if the method is called through a long call chain? Passing the `isTestMode` parameter down all the way through the call chain seems very intrusive. It's a bad thing to break encapsulation on a single method - doing it on many is much, much worse.

Comment: @LBushkin: I totally agree, but since the concept of checking if a method is invoked from a test is a bad idea in the first place I just thought that this approach might lead the OP to a quick "fix" eventhough, granted, it's ugly. But so is checking. The right thing to do is what @Håvard S suggests.

Comment: I understand. The OP really should look into using a mocking framework if this is a technique he needs to use in more than one extreme situation.

Comment: This way can be very quick, which is what is needed sometimes. Mocking is a better way though, if you're not rushing. X

Answer (score 2):

The approach outlined in your question **is** a really bad idea.

A cleaner approach if you want a method to behave differently under test than otherwise, is to refactor out an interface with the method, and inject a different implementation at test time.

E.g.:

```
// Interface whose implementation changes under testing
public interface IChangesUnderTest
{
  void DoesSomething();
}

// Inject this in production
public class ProductionCode : IChangesUnderTest
{
  void DoesSomething() { /* Does stuff */ }
}

// Inject this under test
public class TestCode : IChangesUnderTest
{
  void DoesSomething() { /* Does something else */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the attribute of calling methods by reflection! I will not mention that this is a bed idea, because you know it as I see ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion.

Instead of checking the context, just add in some conditional bug code:

```
#if DEBUG

/* assume you are running in a test environment here */

#endif
```

This is almost not bad.  And if it isn't exactly what you need, you can look into `#define`-ing "TEST" for when you might want your test code to not execute during regular debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a test framework, and know the **testAssemblyName**, you can do as follows:

```
bool IsInUnitTest = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Any(a => a.FullName.StartsWith(testAssemblyName));
```

To be more specificly, if you use NUnit,

```
bool IsRunningFromNUnit =
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Any(
                a=> a.FullName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("nunit.framework"));
```

if you use MSTest, then replace **testAssemblyName** as corresponding **AssemblyName**, maybe is *Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework*.

Comment: Seems simpler to use a #define directive. I often use it to exclude debug code from main builds, with `#if DEBUG` ... `#end if` lines.